# What's the best way to carry a stick clip while climbing?

Tags: rock-climbing

In [this article](https://www.climbernews.com/best-clip-stick/) and this [Outdoors.SE answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/27513/12593), the following use for stick clips is mentioned:

> Having a clip stick means you can take a quickdraw out at a time. Just lower to the next bolt, clip yourself in to that quickdraw to take the weight off the rope (no need to untie). Use the clip stick to unclip the quickdraw above and bring it down. Repeat until you can touch the floor.

However the stick clip which I own is pretty long (57cm/1'10" when folded) and would be unwieldy to attach to your harness. Putting it inside a normal backpack would also be a bit inconvenient as it would stick out and you'd hit your head on it if you lean back. Additionally there's the risk of dropping it to the ground, potentially hurting your belayer.

Is there a good solution for climbing up with a stick clip?

[image: Telescopic stick clip]

Comment: You wouldn't have to commit to carrying it if you can clip in, tie in, go off belay, and haul it up from below with the rope.   Or carry a haul line to toss down.

Comment: Get a smaller clip stick.

Comment: What's your goal for having a stick clip while climbing? Just to reach the next bolt each time? Products exist for that, like the Kong Panic. If your goal is, as that article describes, a method to bail off a route without leaving any gear behind, there are likewise many betters way to do this as well.

Comment: @adeadhead for really difficult (well, difficult for me) routes, I want to be able to clip into the next bolt straight from the previous bolt. I can take a fall just fine in the gym but don't want to take any (lead) falls outdoors. The Kong Panic is too short for this purpose.

Comment: @JonathanReez That’s all fine but you do need to get used to (or rather, prepared to) take a fall outside. It’s not really any worse than the gym. Can’t you practice lead falls inside?

Comment: @Darren I take lead falls every other week in the gym. They're not pleasant and part of the reason why I can climb much harder routes on top rope - I simply don't have the fear of going for the riskiest possible move over and over until I complete the route. With lead, falling is not fun, so I take less risk. Outdoors falling is even less fun due to sharp rocks, random vegetation, belay partner being on uneven terrain, etc. If I can "convert" lead routes to top rope, my climbing would get a lot better.

Comment: @JonathanReez I’m not sure how you’re falling, but it sounds like you’re doing it wrong :) you say you take lead falls, but my question was *do you practice them*? That is, get to a point maybe just above your top runner and let go. Climb a bit higher and do it again. And so on. This builds loads of confidence in the fact that a lead fall on a sport route is vanishingly unlikely to end badly (trad lead falls more so, to which I can personally attest). There are lots of games you can play, like having to immediately fall whenever your belayer tells you. There was a good YouTube series about…

Comment: @JonathanReez …getting over a fear of falling. I’ll see if I can find.

Comment: @Darren conceptually I fully agree with you - I would *love* it if I had zero fear of falling while doing lead. I would also love to have zero fear in bouldering as my climbing is too risk averse there to do the hardest stuff. Let me ask a follow up question.

Comment: @Darren nevermind, [there's already one](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7003/how-to-overcome-the-fear-of-falling-in-lead-climbing). Please add the Youtube videos there if you find them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to buy more equipment, you could tie your tool to a rope or a sling with a knot to give it a positive attachment and orientation control.

[image: Fireman's pike tied to a rope]
This screenshot from the Halifax Fire "Hoisting Tools" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrEtjEIxoj4
video demonstrates several methods using clove hitches or figure eights, plus half hitches to control the shaft.

For a plain shaft like the one you show, you could use some utility cord sling to tie some sort of friction hitch (prusik, kleimheist, etc..) around the handle and a half hitch around the head to give you an attachment point.

[image]

For more permanence, you could tape the friction knot in place.

Answer (score 3):

I'm only speculating, but if I frequently took the clipstick with me on the wall, I'd probably be most concerned with not dropping it while clipping. To address this, I'd drill a hole near the tip of the handle, about where I'm holding the stick on the photo, pass some metal ring through (again, like my finger and thumb go), and then use a sufficiently long loop of cord to attach this to my harness gear loop. This will prevent the stick from folding completely (like the photo shows), but not critically. Welding and epoxy might also work, and avoid the length increase, but I'm not sure if they are as foolproof.

If you find it inconvenient to carry the clipstick on your harness or in your backpack, you might consider a [bandolier](https://dmmwales.com/climbing-products/nuts/bandolier) which would (I imagine) allow you to carry it on your back and pull out like the [Witcher's sword](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vladislav_as_Geralt_from_Witcher_3_at_Igromir_2013.jpg), thus compensating for any perceived uncoolness.

[image]

Comment: Are you protecting from dropping it during use or storage?  For storage, the hole in the clip end is designed for clipping it to your harness.  For during use, you could tie/tape a loop of cord around the handle just below the clamps and use it like a leash/wrist loop during use, or feed it through the clip-end-hole and clip to your harness for storage.

Comment: @DaveX during usage, when I have it extended somewhere over my head and desperately try to hit the sweet spot on that hanger 3 metres above. I don't think a simple loop of cord will catch it if it's dropped, the attachment has to be somewhat more robust.

Comment: I think OP was talking about carrying during climbing.